# Grpc Stream closed before write could take place

Tags: java, stream, grpc, grpc-java

I've got an app that stream data from database via GRPC upon the request of the client.

When the client shutdowns before the streaming is complete. The error is being thrown in the log, but I don't know how to capture it to close the underlying database connection, leaving a db connection leak.

I am using Java and grpc-java version 1.23.0.

```
  try {
... events is a stream retrieved from DB
            StreamObservers.copyWithFlowControl(response, new StreamObserverWithCallbacks<>(
                    responseObserver,
                    count -> {
                        LOGGER.info("Streaming finished);
                        events.close();
                    },
                    ex -> {
                        LOGGER.error("Error streaming",  ex);
                        events.close();
                    }
            ));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Any other exception", e);
            events.close();
        }
```

Here are the exceptions in the logs when I shutdown the client

```
2019-08-27 18:39:34,155 WARN  [grpc-nio-worker-ELG-3-1] i.g.n.s.i.g.n.NettyServerHandler: Stream Error
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception$StreamException: Stream closed before write could take place
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception.streamError(Http2Exception.java:167)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2RemoteFlowController$FlowState.cancel(DefaultHttp2RemoteFlowController.java:481)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2RemoteFlowController$1.onStreamClosed(DefaultHttp2RemoteFlowController.java:105)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2Connection.notifyClosed(DefaultHttp2Connection.java:356)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2Connection$ActiveStreams.removeFromActiveStreams(DefaultHttp2Connection.java:1000)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2Connection$ActiveStreams.deactivate(DefaultHttp2Connection.java:956)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2Connection$DefaultStream.close(DefaultHttp2Connection.java:512)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2Connection.close(DefaultHttp2Connection.java:152)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$BaseDecoder.channelInactive(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:209)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.channelInactive(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:417)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.channelInactive(NettyServerHandler.java:586)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:257)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:243)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:236)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1416)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:257)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:243)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:912)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:816)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:416)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:515)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

As you can see, none of the exceptions have been caught in the try/catch block or on error of the streaming.

Have I missed something? Is there something that I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StreamObserverWithCallbacks is our own class that wrapped around a StreamObserver delegate, so we just needed to do set

```
this.delegate.setOnCancelHandler(() -> onError.accept(new RuntimeException("Stream got cancelled")));
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception you see is actually okay; it is presented because of some gRPC and Netty-internal reasons. It happens when cancellation is involved.

What you are currently missing is observing the cancellation itself. Use [`io.grpc.Context` or `ServerCallStreamObserver`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51092166/4690866) to observe cancellation.

Comment: Thanks for replying. How would I incorporate either one of the suggestion into StreamObservers.copyWithFlowControl() . If seems if I take it all out and only use  ServerCallStreamObserver scso = (ServerCallStreamObserver) responseObserver;
            while (!scso.isCancelled()) {
                if (response.hasNext()) {
                    responseObserver.onNext(response.next());
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

    It's reporting server has processed all records, but clients have not yet received them. I am too new for GRPC

Comment: Oh I figured it out, I needed to do this setOnCancelHandler(() -> onError.accept(new RuntimeException("Stream was cancelled")));