# GRPC Stream closed before write could take place ( grpc_pass through nginx )

Tags: nginx, flutter, dart, grpc, grpc-web

I am using the GRPCWebClientChannel and I have a backend grpc server.

I am using the `grpc: ^2.1.3` package of dart

I am making the request from my `Flutter` app.

I have an nginx reverse proxy setup to point to my grpc backend.
The flutter web client will make the grpc request to the local nginx server.
Nginx will then gprc_pass to the backend URL.

My Client code in dart looks like this :

```
final webChannel = GrpcWebClientChannel.xhr(Uri.parse('http://localhost:8080',));

final client = CreditScoreServiceClient(webChannel,
    options: CallOptions(
        metadata: {
          "Authorization": "Bearer token", 
          "isDebug": "true",
          "locale": "en"
        },timeout:Duration(seconds: 10) ));
resp = await client.getLandingScreen(Empty()) ;
```

Here's my Nginx config :

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  10s;

    #gzip  on;

   upstream securebackend {
    server dev-cabs.172.16.0.80.nip.io:80;
   }

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
        grpc_buffer_size 100M;
            grpc_pass grpc://dev-cabs.172.16.0.80.nip.io:80;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }

    include servers/*;
}
```

The request reaches the backend but gives the following error in backend : `Stream closed before write could take place` :

Here are the logs :

```
2020-03-15 01:07:37,525 :  :  : 127915497 [grpc-default-worker-ELG-1-1]  WARN i.g.n.s.i.g.n.NettyServerHandler - Exception in onDataRead()
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
2020-03-15 01:07:37,526 :  :  : 127915498 [grpc-default-worker-ELG-1-1]  WARN i.g.n.s.i.g.n.NettyServerHandler - Stream Error
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception$StreamException:
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception.streamError(Http2Exception.java:149)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.newStreamException(NettyServerHandler.java:701)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.onDataRead(NettyServerHandler.java:468)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.access$800(NettyServerHandler.java:98)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler$FrameListener.onDataRead(NettyServerHandler.java:724)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder$FrameReadListener.onDataRead(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:236)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger$1.onDataRead(Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:48)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readDataFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:421)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.processPayloadState(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:251)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:160)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger.readFrame(Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:41)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.decodeFrame(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:118)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$FrameDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:390)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:450)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:441)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:656)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:591)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:508)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:470)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
2020-03-15 01:07:37,526 :  :  : 127915498 [grpc-default-worker-ELG-1-1]  WARN i.g.n.s.i.g.n.NettyServerHandler - Stream Error
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception$StreamException: Stream closed before write could take place
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception.streamError(Http2Exception.java:149)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2RemoteFlowController$FlowState.cancel(DefaultHttp2RemoteFlowController.java:480)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2RemoteFlowController$1.onStreamClosed(DefaultHttp2RemoteFlowController.java:104)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2Connection.notifyClosed(DefaultHttp2Connection.java:356)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2Connection$ActiveStreams.removeFromActiveStreams(DefaultHttp2Connection.java:1000)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2Connection$ActiveStreams.deactivate(DefaultHttp2Connection.java:956)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2Connection$DefaultStream.close(DefaultHttp2Connection.java:512)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2Connection$DefaultStream.close(DefaultHttp2Connection.java:518)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.closeStream(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:589)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.processRstStreamWriteResult(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:862)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.access$1000(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:66)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$3.operationComplete(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:786)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$3.operationComplete(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:783)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:485)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:103)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PromiseNotificationUtil.trySuccess(PromiseNotificationUtil.java:48)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.safeSuccess(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:703)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:258)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.removeBytes(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:338)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:428)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:938)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:360)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:905)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1396)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.onError(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:619)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$FrameDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:392)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:450)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:441)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:656)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:591)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:508)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:470)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Did you ever find a root cause? Running into similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you are seeing is not really a problem. It's just a logspam because of some gRPC and Netty-internal reasons. It happens when cancellation is involved.

Check out [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/6943#issuecomment-615466354):

> This issue is related to cancellation, which is caused by
> `maxConnectionAgeGrace()`. If a sender has queued data when it
> receives a cancellation this is triggered, so it should be easy to
> reproduce (I think some of our existing tests may produce this).
> However, it is also not an error. When this happens the stream is
> being thrown away, so it is "okay" that we are throwing away data. It
> truly is just logspam.
>
> This may be a complex order-of-processing issue, or maybe we need to
> check if the stream is cancelled during some particular log statement.

Another [related issue from GitHub](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dart/issues/283).

As mentioned in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57681679), since this happens during cancellation the workaround that you can do is to observe the cancellation itself using [`io.grpc.Context` or `ServerCallStreamObserver`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51092166).